# SurveyMonkey Webhook Event Data

Tags: webhooks, surveymonkey

I am having difficulty interpreting the results of the webhook event data being returned. If this is the data being returned:

```
{
    "name":"Test Webhook",
    "event_id":"EVENT ID HERE",
    "object_type":"response",
    "object_id":"OBJECT ID HERE",
    "event_datetime":"2017-01-12T15:10:18.667701+00:00",
    "event_type":"response_completed"
}
```

I understand that the object_id corresponds to the responseId but I am trying to figure out where the surveyId is?

When we get the event data back, we need to make an API call to:
'surveys/'.$surveyId.'/responses/'.$responseId.'/details' so that we can get the details for processing.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The webhook data sent to your subscription URL has recently been updated. See the details in [the docs](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#webhook-event-data).

The payload has some new values, it looks something like this now (depending on your event type):

```
{
  "name": "My Webhook",
  "filter_type": "collector", (or survey, it's based on how they configure the webhook)
  "filter_id": "123456789",
  "event_type": "response_completed",
  "event_id": "123456789",
  "object_type": "response",
  "object_id": "123456",
  "event_datetime": "2016-01-01T21:56:31.182613+00:00",
  "resources": {
    "respondent_id": "123456789",
    "recipient_id": "123456789",
    "collector_id": "123456789",
    "survey_id": "123456789",
    "user_id": "123456789"
  }
}
```

So if your event was "response_completed" then `object_id` is the response ID. If you filtered to a specific type of survey then the `filter_id` is the survey ID.

As well there is a `resources` key with a bunch of relevant IDs.

Comment: Thanks. They must have just added the resources within a day or two.